# Cannot get items inside a JSON file to use inside an angular partial

Tags: json, angularjs

What I have is this:

- A link to a views/:productId page
- A /views/products folder populated with json files for each product

The problem is this: I get a correct redirect to  the page, but that page gives me {{product.name}} rather than the correct data.

app.js

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/featured.html',
      controller: 'FeaturedCtrl'
    })
    .when('/products', {
      templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
      controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
    })
    .when('/products/:productId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/product-detail.html',
      controller: 'ProductDetailCtrl'
    });
});
```

ProductDetailCtrl

```
angular.module('nameApp')
  .controller('ProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Product',
  function ($scope, $routeParams, Product) {
      $scope.product = Product.get({
        productId: $routeParams.productId
      });
  }]);
```

Products.html

```
<div class="container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a ng-href="#/">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/child">child</a></li>
    <li class="active">{{product.name}}</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">{{product.name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="text-justify">
            {{product.description}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a ng-href="#/">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/child">child</a></li>
    <li class="active">{{product.name}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

productN.json

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "type": [
    "type1",
    "type2",
    "type3",
    "type4",
    "type5",
    "type6"
  ],
  "wood": [
    "wood1",
    "wood2",
    "wood3",
    "wood4",
    "wood5"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does `Product.get` return?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: where is product-detail.html?
The html file you listed is a template to the product list and it controller does not assignment. Can you put your code in a codepen/jsbin so we can debug it?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos I'm *trying* to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), the reason of what I did and that I did not can be found there

Comment: @charlietfl yes it says:
1. A synchronous request XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of the adverse effects on the user experience. Further information http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

2. Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ProductProvider <- Product <- ProductDetailCtrl

Comment: Better show us the `Product` code then. Synchronous ajax call would indeed block all other code running and cause issues with angular rendering. No idea what is causing that

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani Can you show us your Product service?

Comment: @Meir whops. Products.html is indeed product-detail.html. How can I put an angular project on codepen?

Comment: use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), easy to create directory files

Comment: Sorry to everyone, the problem was that was missing the service, probably it has been deleted while saving the file in Brackets (deleting selected code on saving.. oh you, Brackets), now it works.